# How do you unit test a nested function?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nested-function

How would you unit test the nested function `f1()` in the following example?

```
def f():
    def f1():
       return 1
    return 2
```

Or should functions that need testing not be nested?

Comment: I'll put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a similar question in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326910/running-unit-tests-on-nested-functions). But short answer: you can't access an inner function from an outer element.

For testing purposes, maybe an alternative would be to change the inner function for a private outer one?

Answer (score 11):

You don't, because you can't.

You will have to either limit your unit testing to the outer function, or you move the inner function elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same doubt and found a way to get tests going for inner functions.

```
def outer():
    def inner():
        pass

    if __debug__:
        test_inner(inner)
        # return

def test_inner(f):
    f() # this calls the inner function

outer()
```

Basically you can send the inner function as a parameter to the outside and test it as you wish. When calling outer(), your test will run, and since it's a closure, it will preserve any extra property from the outer function (like variables). Using a list, you can send as many functions as you wish. To ignore the **if**, an option is to run the code like that:

```
python -O code.py
```

Comment: This is a very special case solution.  Consider a nested function within a loop, accessing local variables of the outer function (the more common use case for nested functions, IMHO).

Comment: Is this a good practice?