# How can I access an inner class method with pytest (Unit Test)

Tags: python, pytest

Based on some ideas online, I created a decorator class, to track and store the input and output of other functions and methods, which I will need for further tracking of my app.

The decorator works as expected but I don't have an idea, how I could create a Unit Test in order to test the inner method `inner_decorator`

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class InfoWrapper(object):
    """
    Save input and output information of wrapped methods
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._info = dict()

    def cache_data(self, wrapped_function):
        
        def inner_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            result = wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs)
            try:
                _data = result
                _id = args[0]

                self._info[_id] = _data
                logger.debug(f"Module: {wrapped_function.__module__} Method: {wrapped_function.__name__}")
                logger.debug(f"{len(self._info)=} : {_id=}")
            except Exception as ex:
                logger.warning(f"{ex}")
            return result
        return inner_decorator

    @property
    def get_info(self):
        return self._info


info_wrapper = InfoWrapper()


@info_wrapper.cache_data
def my_example(input_id: int):
    return {"test": "ready", "number": input_id*2}


my_example(20)

print(info_wrapper.get_info)
```

Output of this exampple

```
{20: {'test': 'ready', 'number': 40}}
```

I tried to "see" the relationship of the class and this special method in pycharm but I could not see it:

[image]

### Question:

How can I access the inner class method `inner_decorator` with a unit test e.g. pytest?

Comment: `info_wrapper.cache_data` is the inner function. What exactly do you want to do with it?

Comment: If you are really able to see the code there in front of you, just treat it as any other function and write some white-box tests.

Comment: This is only an abstract example related to the code. I have a class method, with a inner function/ method and I want to test this method/ function which is "inside" the class method.

Comment: Could be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606178/how-do-you-unit-test-a-nested-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326910/running-unit-tests-on-nested-functions), what means, I have to move the inner part to a callable function

Comment: If the function/method is really inaccessible, then you should leave it there (surely it will be tested by the class method it is located in) especially if it makes use of variables local to the enclosing method.