# How to mock a function present inside another function in Python?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I want to mock a function present inside another function like this:

```
def parent_function():
    def child_function():
        # mock this function
        return something_1

    child_function()  # calling the child function and doing other things 
    return something_2
```

Here is how I tried to mock it:

```
@patch('package.parent_function.child_function')
def test_some_method(self, mocked_function):
    # doing testing
```

It threw the below error:

```
AttributeError: <function parent_function at 0x7f7d46a2d170> does not have the attribute 'child_function'
```

What am I doing wrong? and how can I solve this problem.

P.S. Please don't suggest me to modify the main code as I am not allowed to do that, I have to do just the testing.

Comment: This is not possible. You cannot patch a nested function, because it is created only at runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running unit tests on nested functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326910/running-unit-tests-on-nested-functions)